# How can i close UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, uiview

I'm new to iOS and Objective-C. I have an application that displays a table view, and opens a new view when click the user clicks on a row.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    DetailViewController *detailController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
    [detailController changeSubjectText:[subject_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    //navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailController];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

In my detail view I have coded:

```
-(IBAction)closeDetail:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"closeDetail");
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

But it's not working. Can anyone help?

---

Can anyone help me?

how i can close view?

download my code in --> http://www.vasuta.com/ios/multiview2.zip

open build and run click one row in "Bulletin Board" DetailView it's open click Close …..

why DetailView is not full screen and why can't close detail view?

i open it wrong or i close it wrong

help me please

didSelectRowAtIndexPath you can see in "GadgetBulletinsTVContoller.m" and close command you can see in "DetailViewController.m"

Thank you very much

ps. sorry for my english skill :(

Comment: thank Perception for edit my topic but my app display many table view

http://a2.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/467294_443782885638094_100000191587335_2063942_2020809123_o.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you creating that window object and why are you trying to add your subview to it?
if you want to add a subview you should add it to the parent, the tableview or the parent of the tableView.

a better idea would be to push a new view controller on the stack that would display the info you want to show.

Here is a tutorial that shows how to push a new view controller when selecting a cell in a tableview [tutorial link](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2011/05/18/tutorial-using-uitableview-adding-a-detail-view-in-xcode-4/) .

EDIT:
in MultipleAppDelegate - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions should look like below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[MultipleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MultipleViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

In GadgetBulletinsTVContoller.h declare a protocol like below:

```
@protocol GadgetBulletinsTVControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)showItemDetails:(id)selectedItem;

@end
```

and a delegate property:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign)id<GadgetBulletinsTVControllerDelegate>delegate;
```

In GadgetBulletinsTVContoller.m synthesize the delegate.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
should look like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{   
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(showItemDetails:)])
    {
        [delegate showItemDetails:[subject_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
}
```

In FirstViewController.m tell the controller to implement the GadgetBulletinsTVControllerDelegate like this:

```
    @interface FirstViewController ()<GadgetBulletinsTVControllerDelegate>

in viewDidLoad method tell the gadgetBulletinsController that his delegate is the FirstViewController class, like this:

if (gadgetBulletinsContoller == nil) {
        gadgetBulletinsContoller = [[GadgetBulletinsTVContoller alloc] init];
        gadgetBulletinsContoller.delegate = self;
    }
```

and implement the GadgetBulletinsTVControllerDelegate's methods:

```
- (void)showItemDetails:(id)selectedItem
{
    if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(showDetailsScreenForItem:)])
    {
        [delegate showDetailsScreenForItem:selectedItem];
    }
}
```

In FirstViewController.h declare a protocol like below:

```
@protocol FirstViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)showDetailsScreenForItem:(id)item;

@end
```

and declare a delegate property like below(don't forget to synthesize in .m file):

```
@property (nonatomic, assign)IBOutlet id<FirstViewControllerDelegate>delegate;
```

In MultipleViewController.xib select the FirstViewController screen and in outlets drag from the delegate to the fileOwner for setting the value of the delegate to the MultipleViewController(you can do this in code if you want to).

In MultipleViewController.m tell the MultipleViewController to implement the FirstViewControllerDelegate protocol like below:

```
@interface MultipleViewController ()<FirstViewControllerDelegate>
```

and implement the protocol method:

```
- (void)showDetailsScreenForItem:(id)item
{
    DetailViewController *detailController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
    [detailController changeSubjectText:item];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
}
```

In DetailViewController modify the closeDetail method to look like this:

```
- (IBAction)closeDetail:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"closeDetail");
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and voila, Your GadgetBulletinsTVController items details are pushed. You need to do the same steps for the other controllers from where you want to show details.

Comment: my app' have many tableview in one view (one page) ... ex.
http://a2.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/467294_443782885638094_100000191587335_2063942_2020809123_o.jpg

when click on row on one tableview i'am not sure i can use navigationController

Comment: i guess you have one data source for each tableview. You need to identify the selected item and then present it pushing a new view controller, modal or not. Using a navigationController is the simplest way.

Comment: please help me ... you can see my code from http://www.vasuta.com/ios/multiview2.zip

Comment: Thank you very much Sorin Antohi
it's work in first controller
i try in other controller

many thank .... you save my life :)

Comment: if i have other data from xml to show in detail maybe message or other
i can add showDetailsScreenForItemxxxx ?

Comment: i hope i understood correctly your question.. in showDetailsScrenForItemxxxx you can show whatever data you want. A good idea would be to create a model class for the data parsed from the xml and pass an instance of that class to the method.

Comment: ok … please help me again … in this code [ download from --> http://www.vasuta.com/ios/multiview2_v2.zip ] 
… why in DetailViewController.m  value in line 38,42,46 and 50 it's have values …
but when i use other var' (in line 39,43,47 and 51) and display in label (line 64 to 69) …
new var' is not value (line 66 to 68) …… ex xml file is http://www.loxleyintranet.com/MobileApplication/xml/bulletins.php …….. many thank again

Comment: yes! ... do it now ... i change [delegate showItemDetails:[subject_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; to [delegate showItemDetails:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@||%@||%@||%@" ,[subject_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[board_id_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[company_id_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[table_name_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]; ......

Comment: and in MultipleViewController i change [detailController changeSubjectText:item]; to NSArray *substr_item = [item componentsSeparatedByString:@"||"]; and use [detailController changeSubjectText:[substr_item objectAtIndex:0]]; ........ thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

instead of removing the view from window just reload the basic view which contains all the table views using `self.window.rootviewcontroller`

**EDIT**

i got the solution by creating appDelegate what you have to do is just described below

First .h and .m file of AppDelegate Here (MultipleAppDelegate)

in .h add

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<UIApplicationDelegate>delegate;
```

in .m add

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

now where ever you like to add detailView just add below in .h and .m files as described

in .h file here(GadgetBulletinsTVContoller)

```
#import "MultipleAppDelegate.h"
```

and in interface one variable like this

```
MultipleAppDelegate *Mydelegate;
```

in .m file in `viewDidLoad` or `loadView` method

```
Mydelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

then at loading the detailView do this

```
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailController];
Mydelegate.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
[Mydelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

now at the detailViewController's .h and .m files
in .h file

```
#import "MultipleAppDelegate.h"
```

and in interface

```
MultipleAppDelegate *appDelegate;
```

in .m file in `viewDidLoad` or `loadView` method

```
appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

and on close button click

```
//Not required
//[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
appDelegate.viewController = [[MultipleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MultipleViewController" bundle:nil];
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = appDelegate.viewController;
[appDelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

That's all it will work fine only problem is that it take's 1 or 2 seconds to navigate and show the multipalViewController

enjoy Coding :)
Happy Coding :)

Comment: please help me ... you can see my code from http://www.vasuta.com/ios/multiview2.zip

Comment: ok i will provide you further info once i got proper solution

Comment: just see the edit this will solve your problem i practically do it

Comment: thank you very much Aalok Parikh
you code it's work for open and close detailview

but if i login in firstview and open detailview
when i clode detailview and back to firstview
it's need login again .... why

but i many thank you and Sorin Antohi for help me in this case :)